# RegExp string filtering - how to allow `-` sign?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

So having such code that filters letters, and `/ ".:=` how to allow `-`?

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>

std::string filter_args(std::string args)
{
    std::cout << boost::erase_all_regex_copy(args, boost::regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9=\"/.: ]+")); 
    return boost::erase_all_regex_copy(args, boost::regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9=\"/.: ]+"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost's default Regex behaviour is Perl-compatible](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/regex/doc/syntax.html), and [man perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) says:

> You can specify a character class, by enclosing a list of characters
>   in `[]`, which will match any character from the list. If the first
>   character after the "[" is "^", the class matches any character not in
>   the list. **Within a list, the "-" character specifies a range, so that
>   `a-z` represents all characters between "a" and "z", inclusive. If you
>   want either "-" or "]" itself to be a member of a class, *put it at the
>   start of the list* (possibly after a "^"), or escape it with a
>   backslash. *"-" is also taken literally when it is at the end of the
>   list, just before the closing "]".*** (The following all specify the same
>   class of three characters: `[-az]`, `[az-]`, and `[a\-z]`. All are
>   different from `[a-z]`, which specifies a class containing twenty-six
>   characters, even on EBCDIC-based character sets.) Also, if you try to
>   use the character classes `\w`, `\W`, `\s`, `\S`, `\d`, or `\D` as endpoints
>   of a range, the "-" is understood literally.

---

So:

```
boost::erase_all_regex_copy(args, boost::regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9=\"/.: -]+"))
```

or

```
boost::erase_all_regex_copy(args, boost::regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9=\\-\"/.: ]+"))
```

(notice the double-backslash; one to escape for the string literal, and the second to escape for the regex).

I recommend the former.

---

Always check out the documentation as your first port of call!

Answer (score 1):

Escape it with `\`. That should work. `\-`.

You will actually have to do it twice. `\\-` One time to escape the `\`, the second to escape the `-`.

Comment: fails with `boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::regex_error> > at memory location 0x003ef0a4..`

Comment: You don't need to escape it at all if you put it in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Put it last inside the brackets, like `[^a-zA-Z0-9=\"/.: -]`.

Comment: @Kabumbus: Because you asked for that character to be included. Why do you think that it shall not be done like this?

Comment: Because normally - means a range, like the a-z you are using there.